# Unexpected behavior with actionlib_tutorials

Tags: ros, actionlib-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the first [actionlib tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29) exactly, first creating a new workspace. I added all dependencies as in the tutorial and building the workspace worked fine. When running the fibonacci_server, the tutorial states:

> You will see something similar to:
>
> [ INFO] 1250790662.410962000: Started
> node [/fibonacci], pid [29267], bound
> on [aqy], xmlrpc port [39746], tcpros
> port [49573], logging to
> [~/ros/ros/log/fibonacci_29267.log],
> using [real] time

However, this info is not displayed. The server runs without error and `rostopic list -v` lists the same topics as in the tutorial. Furthermore, running rqt_graph results in a single block `fibonacci` with two topics `color` and `/fibonacci` as opposed to the graph in the tutorial.

I then continued with the client, following the tutorial precisely again. After creating the fibonacci_client.cpp file and editing the CMakeLists.txt, catkin_make fails:

```
achille@W530:~/Documents/tutorial_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws
Source space: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/src
Build space: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/build
Devel space: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/devel
Install space: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.6
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:

-- ~~  - actionlib_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'actionlib_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(actionlib_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- Generating .msg files for action actionlib_tutorials/Fibonacci /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/src/actionlib_tutorials/action/Fibonacci.action
-- actionlib_tutorials: 7 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at actionlib_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:138 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    fibonacci_client

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
CMake Warning (dev) at actionlib_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:151 (add_dependencies):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
  The dependency target "fibonacci_client" of target "fibonacci_server" does
  not exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: fibonacci_server
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "fibonacci_server".
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/achille/Documents/tutorial_ws/build
Makefile:920: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

The build part of my CMakelists.txt is as follows (dropping comments):

```
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(
  fibonacci_server src/fibonacci_server.cpp
  fibonacci_client src/fibonacci_client.cpp
)

add_dependencies(
  fibonacci_server
  fibonacci_client
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)

target_link_libraries(
  fibonacci_server
  fibonacci_client
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I'm not sure if this error is related to the earlier abnormality. I tried the minimal example for CMakelists.txt that the tutorial provides instead of the autogenerated one. Only when I add in the fibonacci_client, building fails. I tried some suggestions online but none solved this problem.

I'm running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. The actionlib_tutorials package is also installed in /opt/ros/... but I sourced so that roscd yields the correct path.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265281/unexpected-behavior-with-actionlib_tutorials/) by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2017-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-02**:
Can you make sure that you've actually added `add_executable(fibonacci_client src/fibonacci_client.cpp)` (note the `src/` there), and not just `add_executable(fibonacci_client fibonacci_client.cpp)`, or even `add_executable(fibonacci_client)`?

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2017-07-02**:
That's the case. Updated my question with the BUILD part of the CMakeLists.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> add_executable(
> ```

```
  fibonacci_server src/fibonacci_server.cpp
  fibonacci_client src/fibonacci_client.cpp
)
```

I can't answer the first part of your question, but the above is not how `add_executable(..)` works.

See the [CMake documentation for add_executable(..)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html):

> Add an executable to the project using the specified source files.

> ```
> add_executable(<name> [WIN32] [MACOSX_BUNDLE]
> ```

```
               [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL]
               source1 [source2 ...])
```

> Adds an executable target called `<name>` to be built from the source files listed in the command invocation. The `<name>` corresponds to the logical target name and must be globally unique within a project. The actual file name of the executable built is constructed based on conventions of the native platform (such as `<name>.exe` or just `<name>`.

The first argument to `add_executable(..)` is the name of *a single executable*, with all the following arguments being the *source files* that together make up the binary.

In your CMake snippet, you seem to have intended to build both executables with a single `add_executable(..)`. As should now be clear, that doesn't work.

The tutorial you linked to also doesn't do that (note the: "Add the following lines to your `CMakeLists.txt`"), it has the server in its own `add_executable(..)` ([here](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29#Compiling)) and the client as well ([here](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient#Compiling)).

Finally: even if this were possible from the CMake side, it still wouldn't work: there can only be a single entry point in any executable binary and both the server and the client have a `main(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-02**:
Did this also clear up the problem with the output of the server binary?

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2017-07-02**:
It did. Graph looks different from the one on the tutorial though and still has this weird 'color' attribute. Bedankt!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-03**:
The `color` that you see is a bug. See #q249553.

**Comment by [count_dueki](https://answers.ros.org/users/30399/count_dueki/) on 2018-06-17**:
I got the same problem that achille had. even when I follow the guidelines gvdhoorn provided still there is no output from the binary server. But topics with subs and pubs are present, yet not connected to the node. Any ideas?